# Segmentation fault when using @llvm.global_dtors in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, clang, llvm

```
; ModuleID = 'main.ll'
source_filename = "main.ll"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.37.32825"

%X = type { i32 }

@x = global %X zeroinitializer
@.StringLiteral0 = private unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c"D%d\0A\00", align 1
@llvm.global_dtors = appending global [1 x { i32, ptr, ptr }] [{ i32, ptr, ptr } { i32 0, ptr @cleanup, ptr null }]

define void @cleanup() {
entry:
  call void (ptr) @"X.destructor(X&)"(ptr @x)
  ret void
}

declare i32 @printf(ptr, ...)

define void @"X.destructor(X&)"(ptr %self) {
entry:
  %i = getelementptr inbounds %X, ptr %self, i32 0, i32 0
  %0 = load i32, ptr %i, align 4
  %1 = call i32 (ptr, ...) @printf(ptr @.StringLiteral0, i32 %0)
  ret void
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ; call void @cleanup()
  ret i32 0
}
```

This code is a minimal reproducible example for a code that is supposed to call the destructor of an object of type `X`. Since there might be more than one source file to be linked together, there is a `cleanup` function, in which the destructors of all global variables will be called. All `cleanup` functions across all files will be appended to the `@llvm.global_dtors` array and will be called at the end of the program.

This is not what happens, however. This code results in a segmentation fault.

When I compile it and run it in `lldb`, I get the following backtrace:

```
Process 11100 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7fff7c663aca: Access violation writing location 0x00000024
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7c663aca ntdll.dll`TpWorkOnBehalfClearTicket + 394
ntdll.dll`TpWorkOnBehalfClearTicket:
->  0x7fff7c663aca <+394>: incl   0x24(%rax)
    0x7fff7c663acd <+397>: movq   0x18(%rdi), %r12
    0x7fff7c663ad1 <+401>: leaq   0x10(%rdi), %rsi
    0x7fff7c663ad5 <+405>: movq   %r12, -0x19(%rbp)
(lldb) bt
error: output.exe :: Class '__crt_cached_ptd_host::cached<int>::guard' has a member '_copy' of type '__crt_cached_ptd_host::cached<int>' which does not have a complete definition.
(lldb) * thread #1, stop reason = Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7fff7c663aca: Access violation writing location 0x00000024
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff7c663aca ntdll.dll`TpWorkOnBehalfClearTicket + 394
    frame #1: 0x00007fff7c6518e4 ntdll.dll`RtlEnterCriticalSection + 596
    frame #2: 0x00007fff7c6516d2 ntdll.dll`RtlEnterCriticalSection + 66
    frame #3: 0x00007ff765a057a1 output.exe`static int __crt_seh_guarded_call<int>::operator(this=0x00007ff765a750c8, setup=<unavailable>, setup=0x0000000000000000, action=0x0000009ff22ffc60, action=<unavailable>, action=0x0000000000000000, cleanup=0x0000009ff22ffc50, cleanup=<unavailable>, cleanup=0x0000009ff22ffc50)<<lambda_d854c62834386a3b23916ad6dae2782d>,<lambda_303760bc4008a2b3ec4768a30b06a80c> &,<lambda_4780a7ea4f8cbd2590aec34bd14e2bbf> >(class __acrt_lock_stream_and_call::__l2::<lambda_d854c62834386a3b23916ad6dae2782d> *, class common_vfprintf::__l2::<lambda_303760bc4008a2b3ec4768a30b06a80c> & const, class __acrt_lock_stream_and_call::__l2::<lambda_4780a7ea4f8cbd2590aec34bd14e2bbf> *) at internal_shared.h:201
    frame #4: 0x00007ff765a2f45a output.exe`__stdio_common_vfprintf(options=<unavailable>, options=<unavailable>, stream=<unavailable>, stream=<unavailable>, format=<unavailable>, format=<unavailable>, locale=<unavailable>, locale=<unavailable>, arglist="", arglist="") at output.cpp:61
    frame #5: 0x00007ff7659fe7c9 output.exe`printf(_Format=<unavailable>, _Format=<unavailable>, _Format="D%d\n") at stdio.h:960
    frame #6: 0x00007ff7659e7272 output.exe`X.destructor(X&) + 18
    frame #7: 0x00007ff7659e7250 output.exe`cleanup + 16
    frame #8: 0x00007ff765a00afd output.exe`_initterm(first=<unavailable>, first=<unavailable>, last=<unavailable>, last=0x00007ff765a5ff20, last=<unavailable>) at initterm.cpp:21
    frame #9: 0x00007ff765a00d6c output.exe`static void <lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c>::operator(this=0x0000000000000fa0)() at exit.cpp:242
    frame #10: 0x00007ff765a00bad output.exe`static void __crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator(this=0x0000000000000000, setup=<unavailable>, setup=0x0000000000000000, action=0x0000009ff22ffe38, action=<unavailable>, action=0x02100800000906ea, cleanup=0x0000009ff22ffe24, cleanup=<unavailable>, cleanup=0x0000009ff22ffe24)<<lambda_d80eeec6fff315bfe5c115232f3240e3>,<lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c> &,<lambda_2358e3775559c9db80273638284d5e45> >(class __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_d80eeec6fff315bfe5c115232f3240e3> *, class common_exit::__l2::<lambda_6e4b09c48022b2350581041d5f6b0c4c> & const, class __acrt_lock_and_call::__l2::<lambda_2358e3775559c9db80273638284d5e45> *) at internal_shared.h:224
    frame #11: 0x00007ff765a00ee3 output.exe`static void common_exit(return_code=<unavailable>, return_code=-231736848, return_code=-231736848, cleanup_mode=<unavailable>, cleanup_mode=<unavailable>, cleanup_mode=_crt_exit_full_cleanup, return_mode=<unavailable>, return_mode=<unavailable>, return_mode=_crt_exit_terminate_process) at exit.cpp:195
    frame #12: 0x00007ff7659e9dd3 output.exe`static int __scrt_common_main_seh() at exe_common.inl:295
    frame #13: 0x00007fff7a8c257d kernel32.dll`BaseThreadInitThunk + 29
    frame #14: 0x00007fff7c68aa58 ntdll.dll`RtlUserThreadStart + 40
(lldb)
```

When I comment this line:

```
@llvm.global_dtors = appending global [1 x { i32, ptr, ptr }] [{ i32, ptr, ptr } { i32 0, ptr @cleanup, ptr null }]
```

and uncomment this line:

```
; call void @cleanup()
```

or in other words, when I run the `cleanup` function manually at the end of the main function and get rid of the `@llvm.global_dtors` array, the program works as intended.

This error happens only on Windows. The same code works as intended on Linux.

Comment: You'll need to use a debugger that allows you to break when the exception is raised. The call stack shown here doesn't appear to be useful.

Comment: Looks a bit fishy to call `printf()` during CRT shutdown. Might want to go with something that can stand on its own feet (like `::OutputDebugString()`).

Comment: Never mind, I got that backwards. [`_initterm()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e) is called during initialization. It is responsible for, e.g., initializing objects with static storage duration. It's strange that your destructor runs during initialization. Might want to step through the code to see what's going on here.